# Generate code from state diagram

Tags: enterprise-architect

I want to generate C++ code from a State Diagram (Harrel FSM) and I'm wondering whether this is possible with EA, and if, how to go about generating code.

I've followed the example at [Sparx: Generate From Behavioral Models](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/software_engineering/code_generation_from_behaviora.html), but when I look at the generated code it consists of skeleton code that does not include any state transitions etc. I've seen an [example](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/software_engineering/code_generated_from_state_mach.html) of assumedly code generated by EA in their online help, so it does seem to be possible, but I cannot find any concrete examples of how.

Could anyone give me some direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you able to generate behavioral code from the examples in the EAExample model?

If not, you'll need to confirm which edition of Enterprise Architect you are using. Code generation from behavioral models such as State Machines is only available in the Business and Software Engineering, Systems Engineering and Ultimate editions of EA.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, we have the corporate version which therefore does not support this feature. It does however have code generation as part of the menu option, which lead me to believe that this was possible.